# Aptana ruby code assist features not working for erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana3

I'm using Aptana 3.2.1.201207261642 on OSX 10.8

F3 to open declaration / go to definition works on .rb files, but not on .erb files.  I get the popup menu, but the actions don't do anything.

Also, code completion (ctrl+space) doesn't suggest my local project classes. How do I configure Aptana to index my project classes?

FWIW, these features work fine on a PHP project.