# Aptana Studio 3 ERB files Syntax Highlighting and Source Code navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, erb, aptana3

I have just started using Aptana Studio 3 for working on Ruby-on-Rails projects.
While navigating the source code I found following features missing:

1. In ERB files there is no block start/end or if..end start/end highlighting.I browsed through the Settings under *Window/Preferences/Aptana Studio/Editors/ERB* Is there any setting available to enable the same?
2. In ERB files if there is a partial included, then to view the code in the included partial I need to search the partial using **Ctrl + T** and type in the exact name of the partial (starting with UNDERSCORE) to open it.Isn't there any shortcut to directly jump to the partial file from the ERB file?
3. In ERB/HAML files, hitting F3 on a method invoked on an object in the code opens up *Go to Definition 1* and *Open Declaration 2* but nothing happens.On the other hand, doing the same action on any method in .rb files shows a list of file(s)/open the file containing the selected method.Found a related question here with no replies yet: [Aptana ruby code assist features not working for erb files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822803/aptana-ruby-code-assist-features-not-working-for-erb-files)

Can anybody from Aptana team comment/guide on above?

Thanks.